# Python - Crashing when running hdf5 files

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm currently switching to using my terminal for opening python files. In particular, i'm testing out scripts I use to make sure everything runs accordingly.

I'm having certain file that is acting troublesome when trying to open it. It contains

```
from os.path import isfile
import numpy as np
import h5py

def gcPath(basePath,snapNum,chunkNum=0):
    """ Return absolute path to a group catalog HDF5 file (modify as needed). """
    gcPath = basePath + '/groups_%03d/' % snapNum
    filePath1 = gcPath + 'groups_%03d.%d.hdf5' % (snapNum, chunkNum)
    filePath2 = gcPath + 'fof_subhalo_tab_%03d.%d.hdf5' % (snapNum, chunkNum)

    if isfile(filePath1):
        return filePath1
    return filePath2

def offsetPath(basePath, snapNum):
    """ Return absolute path to a separate offset file (modify as needed). """
    offsetPath = basePath + '../postprocessing/offsets/offsets_%03d.hdf5' % snapNum

    return offsetPath

def loadObjects(basePath,snapNum,gName,nName,fields):
    """ Load either halo or subhalo information from the group catalog. """
    result = {}

    # make sure fields is not a single element
    if isinstance(fields, basestring):
        fields = [fields]

    # load header from first chunk
    with h5py.File(gcPath(basePath,snapNum),'r') as f:

        header = dict( f['Header'].attrs.items() )
        result['count'] = f['Header'].attrs['N'+nName+'_Total']

        if not result['count']:
            print 'warning: zero groups, empty return (snap='+str(snapNum)+').'
            return result

        # if fields not specified, load everything
        if not fields:
            fields = f[gName].keys()

        for field in fields:
            # verify existence
            if not field in f[gName].keys():
                raise Exception("Group catalog does not have requested field ["+field+"]!")

            # replace local length with global
            shape = list(f[gName][field].shape)
            shape[0] = result['count']

            # allocate within return dict
            result[field] = np.zeros( shape, dtype=f[gName][field].dtype )

    # loop over chunks
    wOffset = 0

    for i in range(header['NumFiles']):
        f = h5py.File(gcPath(basePath,snapNum,i),'r')

        if not f['Header'].attrs['N'+nName+'_ThisFile']:
            continue # empty file chunk

        # loop over each requested field
        for field in fields:
            # shape and type
            shape = f[gName][field].shape

            # read data local to the current file
            if len(shape) == 1:
                result[field][wOffset:wOffset+shape[0]] = f[gName][field][0:shape[0]]
            else:
                result[field][wOffset:wOffset+shape[0],:] = f[gName][field][0:shape[0],:]


        wOffset += shape[0]
        f.close()

    # only a single field? then return the array instead of a single item dict
    if len(fields) == 1:
        return result[fields[0]]

    return result

def loadSubhalos(basePath,snapNum,fields=None):
    """ Load all subhalo information from the entire group catalog for one snapshot
       (optionally restrict to a subset given by fields). """

    return loadObjects(basePath,snapNum,"Subhalo","subgroups",fields)

def loadHalos(basePath,snapNum,fields=None):
    """ Load all halo information from the entire group catalog for one snapshot
       (optionally restrict to a subset given by fields). """

    return loadObjects(basePath,snapNum,"Group","groups",fields)

def loadHeader(basePath,snapNum):
    """ Load the group catalog header. """
    with h5py.File(gcPath(basePath,snapNum),'r') as f:
        header = dict( f['Header'].attrs.items() )

    return header

def load(basePath,snapNum):
    """ Load complete group catalog all at once. """
    r = {}
    r['subhalos'] = loadSubhalos(basePath,snapNum)
    r['halos']    = loadHalos(basePath,snapNum)
    r['header']   = loadHeader(basePath,snapNum)
    return r

def loadSingle(basePath,snapNum,haloID=-1,subhaloID=-1):
    """ Return complete group catalog information for one halo or subhalo. """
    if (haloID < 0 and subhaloID < 0) or (haloID >= 0 and subhaloID >= 0):
        raise Exception("Must specify either haloID or subhaloID (and not both).")

    gName = "Subhalo" if subhaloID >= 0 else "Group"
    searchID = subhaloID if subhaloID >= 0 else haloID

     # old or new format
    if 'fof_subhalo' in gcPath(basePath,snapNum):
        # use separate 'offsets_nnn.hdf5' files
        with h5py.File(offsetPath(basePath,snapNum),'r') as f:
             offsets = f['FileOffsets/'+gName][()]
    else:
        # use header of group catalog
        with h5py.File(gcPath(basePath,snapNum),'r') as f:
        offsets = f['Header'].attrs['FileOffsets_'+gName]

    offsets = searchID - offsets
    fileNum = np.max( np.where(offsets >= 0) )
    groupOffset = offsets[fileNum]

    # load halo/subhalo fields into a dict
    result = {}

    with h5py.File(gcPath(basePath,snapNum,fileNum),'r') as f:
        for haloProp in f[gName].keys():
            result[haloProp] = f[gName][haloProp][groupOffset]

    return result
```

Basically, what this file does is that it retrieves defined hdf5 files from my user directory for analysis.

If I were to run it through my python environment, I'm returned with

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.13) thread 0:
  #000: H5T.c line 4495 in H5T_path_find(): unable to initialize conversion function
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #001: H5Tconv.c line 8622 in H5T__conv_double_ulong(): disagreement about datatype size
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #002: H5T.c line 2340 in H5T_register(): unable to locate/allocate conversion path
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #003: H5T.c line 4495 in H5T_path_find(): unable to initialize conversion function
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #004: H5Tconv.c line 8568 in H5T__conv_float_ulong(): disagreement about datatype size
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #005: H5T.c line 2340 in H5T_register(): unable to locate/allocate conversion path
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #006: H5T.c line 4495 in H5T_path_find(): unable to initialize conversion function
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #007: H5Tconv.c line 8650 in H5T__conv_ldouble_long(): disagreement about datatype size
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #008: H5T.c line 2340 in H5T_register(): unable to locate/allocate conversion path
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #009: H5T.c line 4495 in H5T_path_find(): unable to initialize conversion function
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #010: H5Tconv.c line 8595 in H5T__conv_double_long(): disagreement about datatype size
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #011: H5T.c line 2340 in H5T_register(): unable to locate/allocate conversion path
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #012: H5T.c line 4495 in H5T_path_find(): unable to initialize conversion function
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #013: H5Tconv.c line 8541 in H5T__conv_float_long(): disagreement about datatype size
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #014: H5T.c line 2340 in H5T_register(): unable to locate/allocate conversion path
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #015: H5T.c line 4495 in H5T_path_find(): unable to initialize conversion function
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #016: H5Tconv.c line 7858 in H5T__conv_ulong_ldouble(): disagreement about datatype size
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #017: H5T.c line 2340 in H5T_register(): unable to locate/allocate conversion path
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #018: H5T.c line 4495 in H5T_path_find(): unable to initialize conversion function
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #019: H5Tconv.c line 7831 in H5T__conv_ulong_double(): disagreement about datatype size
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #020: H5T.c line 2340 in H5T_register(): unable to locate/allocate conversion path
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #021: H5T.c line 4495 in H5T_path_find(): unable to initialize conversion function
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #022: H5Tconv.c line 7804 in H5T__conv_ulong_float(): disagreement about datatype size
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #023: H5T.c line 2340 in H5T_register(): unable to locate/allocate conversion path
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #024: H5T.c line 4495 in H5T_path_find(): unable to initialize conversion function
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #025: H5Tconv.c line 7777 in H5T__conv_long_ldouble(): disagreement about datatype size
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #026: H5T.c line 2340 in H5T_register(): unable to locate/allocate conversion path
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #027: H5T.c line 4495 in H5T_path_find(): unable to initialize conversion function
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #028: H5Tconv.c line 7751 in H5T__conv_long_double(): disagreement about datatype size
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #029: H5T.c line 2340 in H5T_register(): unable to locate/allocate conversion path
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #030: H5T.c line 4495 in H5T_path_find(): unable to initialize conversion function
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #031: H5Tconv.c line 7726 in H5T__conv_long_float(): disagreement about datatype size
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object


Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "groupcat.py", line 6, in <module>
        import h5py
  File         "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from . import _conv
  File "h5py/h5t.pxd", line 14, in init h5py._conv (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/_conv.c:6961)
  File "h5py/h5t.pyx", line 139, in init h5py.h5t (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:20285)
  File "h5py/h5t.pyx", line 73, in h5py.h5t.lockid (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:2565)
  File "h5py/h5t.pyx", line 42, in h5py.h5t.typewrap (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:2199)
TypeError: Unable to initialize conversion function (Disagreement about datatype size)
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have previously used jupyter, which had a large list a packages pre-installed, so a problem could be that I do not a certain package installed. But looking at the traceback error, it seems the problem is `h5py`. But have `h5py` already installed.

Comment: Try to use `driver` parameter : `h5py.File(fname, mode='r', driver='core')`

Answer (score 2):

Your example code is rather long. A more concise example would make it easier to help.

With HDF5 errors, typically the most important error is the first to appear, here "unable to initialize conversion function". What type of data do you have in the HDF5 file? Can they be mapped to NumPy datatypes?